# Codeigniter : Adding 2 variables to array in a for loop

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, for-loop

I have:

```
for ($i=0; $i < 10; $i++) { 
        $date = Date('Y-m-d', strtotime("-$i days"));
        $numar = $this->Misc->get($date);

        // here a want to add to a array $date and $number

}
```

When using a foreach loop on the array i want to get:

```
Date : X   Number : Y
Date : X1  Number : Y1
Date : X2  Number : Y2
```

Comment: stackoverflow is not "a beginners guide to PHP". Echo'ing some data in a format is lesson 1 in every tutorial. Read it there.

Comment: Please read the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) and explain what you don't understand. You should be able to solve this yourself. Also, it has nothing to do with Codeigniter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 $arr_outupt = array();
 for ($i=0; $i < 10; $i++) { 
    $date = Date('Y-m-d', strtotime("-$i days"));
    $numar = $this->Misc->get($date);

    $arr_output[] = array("date"=>$date, "number"=>$numar);
 }

 echo "<table>";
 foreach($arr_output as $arr_temp)
 {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>Date : </td>";
    echo "<td>".$arr_temp['date']."</td>";
    echo "<td>Number : </td>";
    echo "<td>".$arr_temp['number']."</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
 }
 echo "</table>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this its quite simple

```
$new_array = array();
for ($i=0; $i < 10; $i++) { 
    $date = Date('Y-m-d', strtotime("-$i days"));
    $numar = $this->Misc->get($date);

    // here a want to add to a array $date and $number
    $new_array[] = array('Date' => $date, 'Number' => $numar );
}
```